# Hydrogen atom in void

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology, gravity, space-expansion, hydrogen

We have a hydrogen atom, in a gravitationally bound system nothing interesting happens to it. Let's put it in an empty world where there are only an electron and a proton. Several forces act on it: gravitational, electromagnetic, and since we have only two bodies, the expansion of the universe should work. The question is how to express through the Hubble constant and calculate the force of this expansion.
As pointed out to me, to solve this problem, we need to consider the case where we have two particles without electromagnetic interaction, for example 2 neutrons.
As I understood the solution must be sought from the Friedman equations.
This is hard for me since I will only be in my 2nd year at university

Comment: There are some misconceptions here. A universe containing just a hydrogen atom would not expand so there would be no force on the atom. We could put the atom in some empty part of our expanding universe, but the expansion is a large scale phenomenon and on small scales the spacetime is not expanding so again there would be no force. But your question could be interpreted as asking what the four-acceleration due to the expansion is for a stationary observer in a Friedmann (or de Sitter) geometry. That could be calculated from the metric.

Comment: This may be the answer to my question. But why is there no expansion at short distances? And if there is, but very little, can it be estimated? The subtask about 2 neutrons is given just to estimate it at large distances because in structure the gravitational and electromagnetic interactions are the same, i.e. from 2 neutrons it is possible to make the same hydrogen (not in usual sense of the term) but with much bigger radius. It turns out that expansion should definitely act on it.  And please tell me how to calculate the expansion from the metric

Comment: The "expanding" geometry is the FLRW metric and this is the solution for a uniform distribution of matter. If the matter distribution is non-uniform, which looking around us it clearly isn't, the the geometry is not FLRW. However on a large enough scale a few billion light years) the average density **is** uniform so when viewed at a large scale the geometry is approximately FLRW.

Comment: Expansion of space is nothing but a coordinate choice. If there is no expanding material in the universe, there is not necessarily a reason to make that choice. Or alternatively, you can choose any expansion rate that is convenient, e.g. you can say the initial expansion rate is equal to the initial rate of separation of your two neutrons.